# The same thing is printed twice - JS Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I created an Object, which has 2 arrays in it. When I'm trying to print its elements in console, it is printed twice.

```
const err1 = {
    "type": new Array(),
    "desc": new Array()
}

err1.type.push("a","b");
err1.desc.push("ananas","banana");

var errD = new String();
var errT = new String();


err1.type.forEach(function(el, ind){
    errT += `Type: ${el}`;
    errD += `Description: ${err1.desc[ind]}`;
    console.log(`ERROR: \n${errT}\n${errD}`);
});
```

Console:

```
ERROR: 
Type: a
Description: ananas
---------------------------- (console line)
ERROR: 
Type: aType: b
Description: ananasDescription: banana
```

It doesn't matter if the String is already in the array or I push it into it. I've also tried to console them through a for loop - result is the same.

Why is it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're appending, try this:

```js
const err1 = {
    "type": new Array(),
    "desc": new Array()
}

err1.type.push("a","b");
err1.desc.push("ananas","banana");

var errD = new String();
var errT = new String();


err1.type.forEach(function(el, ind){
    errT = `Type: ${el}`;
    errD = `Description: ${err1.desc[ind]}`;
    console.log(`ERROR: \n${errT}\n${errD}`);
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I actually forgot about that.